What is the "execution mode language" in Office?
Office VBA allows you to query the language used by a particular Office application. For example, executing:
? Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)

in the immediate window will yield 1031 (German) on my system, since this is what I chose as my Office UI language.

The LanguageSettings.LanguageID property supports the following MsoAppLanguageID enum values as a parameter:



Name
Value
Description




msoLanguageIDExeMode
4
Execution mode language.


msoLanguageIDHelp
3
Help language.


msoLanguageIDInstall
1
Install language.


msoLanguageIDUI
2
User interface language.


msoLanguageIDUIPrevious
5
User interface language used prior to the current user interface language.



I understand the meaning of the latter four values, but what on earth is the execution mode language?

Note: Some trial and error tests suggest that this is the Windows region/locale setting that was active when the Office application started (3079 = "German (Austria)" on my system), but I'd prefer an authoritative source for this.

https://documentation.help/MS-Office-VB/ofproLanguageID.htm

Not exactly hard to find: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa210697(v=office.11)

@macropod: Oh! I didn't think about checking old, obsolete versions of the documentation. I wonder why they removed it from the current version...
